# Конвейер unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать конвейер на юнити.. Не просто передвижение объекта, а строго по центру конвейера. Вот код, который просто передвигает объект, лежащий на данном конвейере, без позиционирования в центре.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class moveobject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Collider, Cube;
    public float rotationY;
    private Vector3 MoveObject = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    public float Speed = 1f;
    public float ScrollX = 0.18f;
    private void Update()
    {
        rotationY = Cube.transform.rotation.y;//Направление обьекта
        MoveObject = -transform.right;
    }
    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 9 || collision.gameObject.layer == 10)
        {
                Collider = collision.gameObject;//Движение обьекта
                collision.gameObject.transform.position += MoveObject * Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        } 
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
        if (other.gameObject.layer == 9 || other.gameObject.layer == 10) other.gameObject.GetComponent<Cristal>().ActiveCrs = false;
    }
}
```

Нужно, что бы объект:
При переходе на другой конвейер не ускорялся и шел строго по центру конвейера (сотки не принимаются).
Вот скрины конвейера[image: Конвейер 1]

На данный момент движение происходит так:
[image: Как сейчас]

А нужно, что бы шел он так:
[image: Как нужно]

Конвейер состоит из 2 объектов: куба и плоскости.
На плоскости стоит данный скрипт и скрипт анимации. (box Colider is trigger)
На кубу стоит только бокс колайдер, чтобы объект никуда не проваливался.
Можете помочь с реализацией данного проекта?

Comment: Если нужно, могу скинуть мою идею реализации данного конвейера

Comment: сделать корридор из коллайдеров? (:

Comment: @StrangerintheQ неа.. Это очень сложно будет, делать динамический подбор коллайдеров при каждом случае.. Это во первых.. А во вторых, позиционирование будет не точным, с этим большие проблемы..

Comment: Исходя из требования "все должно двигаться точно по центру", осталось попробовать только сплайны, вы попробовали это решение?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Изучаю данную технологию

Answer (score 1):

Задай траэкторию движения используя сплайны. Например, можно использовать [Hermite Spline Controller](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Hermite_Spline_Controller)

В таком случае не нужно будет писать код вообще.

Как вариант 2: можно сохранять направление движения в коде на некоторую задержку перед тем как брать новое направление движения. Но эт хреновый костыль.

Как вариант 3: можно отделить визуальную составляющую от "реального" конвеера. То есть смоделировать таким макаром конвеер, что бы он выглядел точно так же, но реальные конвеерные плоскости (те, которые с коллайдерами, но без MeshRenderer) были вот такими:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В таком случае скрипт в вопросе должен сработать.

Вариант 4: Альтернатива сплайнам: вручную отметить путь созданными EmptyObject-ами.

Допустим обьект попадает в точку EmptyObject1,  Срабатывает триггер, по которому ищется EmptyObject со следующим номером. У этого номера берутся координаты следующей точки. Когда доходит обьект до следующей точки все по кругу - срабатывает тригер и ящик начинает двигатся к следующей точке с некоей скоростью.

Но это делать глупо если есть сплайны.

Comment: ставя минус не забывайте писать почему это плохой ответ.

Comment: Минус не ставил, но объясню, почему этот ответ плох: про навмеш написан откровенный бред, 3-4 пункты без пояснения, хотелось бы видеть "ответ", а не комментарий, куда копать. А самый интересный ответ про сплайны, опять же, только ссылка, ну про сплайны я тоже знаю, как и куча других людей, всем теперь писать ответ с единственный словом: "сплайны"? :)

Comment: Еще раз поясню, что позиционирование должно быть точное! сотка влево, сотка вправо не принимаются!!

Comment: @tebenkov2222 Со сплайнами же будет идеальная точность. Чем конкретно вариант со сплайнами не подходит?

Comment: @Andrew, вариант со сплайнами еще не рассматривал как должное, посмотрю чуть позже, скажу что и как

Comment: @Andrew, по сплайнам.. и как мне сделать динамику?

Comment: @Andrew, он может на том же блоке прямо ехать.. а может вообще с конвейера упасть, то есть не переходить на другие конвейера, а может и вправо повернуть.. Как вот это реализовать с помощью сплайнов?
На сколько я понимаю, сплайны замкнутые, и объект будет двигаться по замкнутой траектории, я правильно понял?

Comment: И да.. еще загвосточка здесь есть.. А если я этот объект в руки возьму (проект для вр) Он же просто не возьмется, правильно?.. ну допустим, сделали мы отвязку.. взяли все так и предмет.. НО когда мы обратно положим его на конвейер, он должен сам сперва подстроится к центру, и продолжить следовать дальше..

Comment: Можно с 4 попробовать, и динамика не большая  есть, и подстроить можно.. Можно и так попробовать, но снова, посмотрите предыдущий комент

Comment: 1. сплайны не обязательно замкнутые. 2. Ты можешь тригером помещать обьект на сплайн что бы двигать. И тригером снимать обьект со сплайна в конце линии что бы он падал. 3. Ты можешь беря в руки предмет отвязать от сплайна.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой вариант:
при вхождении перемещаемого объекта в триггер какого либо из блоков конвейера - сперва центрируй этот объект в этом блоке конвейера

к примеру создай на каждом блоке конвейера точку в центре блока и опиши перемещение в эту точку сразу при вхождении в триггер

и после того как перемещаемый объект достигнет центра блока конвейера (*к примеру ты можешь определить это установив еще один маленький триггер по центру ну или любым другим способом*) далее останавливай перемещение к центру блока конвейера и запускай объект дальше по заданному блоком конвейера направлению

может быть немного костыльно, но если все грамотно описать, работать будет как часы

Comment: Я так и пытаюсь сейчас сделать.. проблема с позиционированием. он входит в оба триггера и надо как то сделать так, чтобы он либо завершал до конца движение и переходил на новый блок, или при первом включении в блок, пока до конца из него не выйдет, на новый не выходить.. Вот с этим пока что прям серьезные проблемы..

Comment: возможно тебе следует сделать так, что когда перемещаемый объект как только входит (точнее касается) в новый триггер - останавливал всю прежнюю логику перемещения и сразу запускалось перемещение к центру нового блока, главное правильно описать условия

Answer (score 1):

не могу писать в комментарии так что вот:

не знаю существует ли такая возможность,но можно разделить соседние плоскости конвейера по диагонали и тогда все объекты будут двигаться по своей "полосе", но к концу приходить будут в разное время

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: еще раз объясню.. В частных случаях можно и так сделать.. Но у меня всегда случаи разные, и делать динамический подбор плоскости под каждый случай очень сложно

Comment: И тем более он должен ТОЛЬКО по центру, и всегда по центру двигаться..

Comment: поля конвейера только в прямоугольной конфигурации бывают, или могут быть любой формы? и тянуться в любом направлении? Если он бывает только в одной плоскости и квадратами то все проще чем кажется, просто нужно задать скрипт для переходной плоскости в которых объект будет обрабатываться по другому, тобиш идет до центра плоскости и поворачивает, сорь за совет нуба